# Remove clone issue permission

Tags: youtrack

In my YouTrack installation I want to remove the grant for clone an issue to prevent Spam of issues similar and avoid to have issues with tag/versions field populated incorrectly.

I found nothing into configuration panel to disable clone action.

There is a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the Clone issue action is managed by the workflow, you need to open the Projects -> project_name -> Workflows page, find the "Clone Issue" workflow and deactivate the both rules:
[image]

Make it for each project, or, if you need this in the whole instance, open Administration -> Workflows, choose the "Clone Issue" and in the drop-down many deselect the projects.
[image]